# Is visual tree is loaded even when control is not in view in wpf

Tags: wpf

Is visual tree is loaded even when control is not in view.For instance lets say i have a tab control which contains a grid.Now if i have not switched to this tab, is the visual tree of grid get loaded or it will be loaded when i switch to this tab.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The VisualTree has not been built before the tab is brought into view. There are a few ways you can force the visual tree to be built prior to it being visible

- You could call [ApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx) on the element and recursively on any child elements.
- You could call [LoadContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent.aspx) which creates a temporary visual tree, check out the sample on the MSDN page.